# Identity Server 4: Using EntityFramework Core for configuration and operational data

Tags: identityserver4

Following this tutorial, https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html, when I run the program to perform the migration, the database and all the tables are able to be created but it hits this error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
> 'RequireRequestObject', table 'xxx.dbo.Clients'; column does not allow
> nulls. INSERT fails.

This is the migration script generated:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Clients",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Enabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    ClientId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: false),
                    ProtocolType = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: false),
                    RequireClientSecret = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    ClientName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: true),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 1000, nullable: true),
                    ClientUri = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2000, nullable: true),
                    LogoUri = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2000, nullable: true),
                    RequireConsent = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AllowRememberConsent = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    RequirePkce = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AllowPlainTextPkce = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    RequireRequestObject = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2000, nullable: true),
                    FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    BackChannelLogoutUri = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2000, nullable: true),
                    BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AllowOfflineAccess = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
                    AccessTokenLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    AuthorizationCodeLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ConsentLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    RefreshTokenUsage = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    AccessTokenType = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    EnableLocalLogin = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    IncludeJwtId = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    ClientClaimsPrefix = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: true),
                    PairWiseSubjectSalt = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: true),
                    Created = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    Updated = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    LastAccessed = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    UserSsoLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    UserCodeType = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
                    DeviceCodeLifetime = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    NonEditable = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Clients", x => x.Id);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that the migration tries to insert some data into your database, while the code in the question is about creating the table and that operation should not cause that error.

So I think the problem is in your code that seeds the database with clients and there the RequireRequestObject flag is not set to false or true.

The RequireRequestObject is also a new field in v4.0x of IdentityServer4, and perhaps you have some version mismatch somewhere? or that the code that seeds the data does not set this field.

So, to fix it, just set the RequireRequestObject field in your database seed code or in the code that generates the insert into the Clients table.